# Is there a bug in my IDE - Can't enter values in console

Tags: java, netbeans

I am unable to input anything from my console after i have run my file.

I am running the following code in main method:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s3 = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered string "+s3);
int a = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("You entered integer "+a)
```

I have also imported java.util.Scanner prior to running.

There is no error in the import as no error is raised by the IDE while running, I am just unable to enter any value through the console.

Is there any setting or mode i have to configure in my IDE to be able to input values from the console?

I am using Netbeans IDE 11.3 on macOSX

Comment: Since this seems to be a small program, please post all of it.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this is caused by a bug in your IDE or a settings problem.  However 1) it is unclear what the complete program looks like, 2) how you are running it, or 3) which "console" you are referring to.  Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a clear explanation of how you are running it.

Comment: sry, cannot reproduce on on Win (7), Netbeans11.3 (with a simple pstvm around this code ..and "Run File" on a maven project) ... feel free to lookup existing/create a new issue [@netbeans](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/).

Comment: Your code is also working fine for me using NetBeans 11.3. I'm not sure if you are aware, but when you run the application focus is not automatically set to the "(run)" window. You must first click in that window before submitting something from the keyboard. If you still have problems please update your question with a screen shot of the application's "(run)" window once the application starts and you have clicked in the window and submitted something. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your isssue.